# Пустое место между div html

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите почему так происходит. Вот макет:
http://jsfiddle.net/XzQw7/1/
В нём всё отображается как надо.

Затем в тег <article> добавляю заголовок <h1> и между тегами <header> и <article> появляется свободное место.
http://jsfiddle.net/XzQw7/1/

Почему так и как это исправить?

Спасибо.

Comment: @andreyqin я сбросил margin, как вы советуете, и вновь добавил margin для h1 - это поможет - посмотрите http://jsfiddle.net/XzQw7/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждого элемента есть стили по умолчанию, в данном случае h1 имеет `margin: .67em 0`, поэтому и образуется этот отступ.

Для справки - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

Чтобы не происходило подобного, рекомендуется в начале стилевого документа обнулять внешние и внутренние отступы для всех элементов на странице:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: @temagr а каким образом совет сбросить все отступы помог вам? Лично меня это оставило без отступов

Comment: @helplz, если вам нужны отступы у других элементов, то вы можете просто сбросить отступ у h1. Я написал, как лучше делать, чтобы избегать подобных проблем при верстке.

Comment: @andreyqin мне у h1 нужен отступ, но чтобы не было именно такого отступа. Как ваше предложение может быть решением проблемы?

Comment: @helplz, автор не понимал, откуда берется отступ, при добавлении h1 в разметку, я ему объяснил. Если вам нужен какой-то определенный отступ - выставьте его. В чем проблема?

Comment: @andreyqin у меня такая же ситуация как у @temagr
на странице появляется непонятный белый промежуток. я делаю по вашему ответу, который принял автор - белое пространство исчезает, но вместе с ним пропадает отступ у h1. мне нужен отступ у h1, но не нужен этот белый кусок

Comment: @andreyqin заменить h1 на паддинг кстати работает

Comment: @helplz, данные правила обнуляют отступы у всех элементов на странице. После этого вам достаточно задать отступ необходимому элементу, в вашем случае это h1. Чем хорошо данное правило? Предположим, вам необходимо жестко задать отступ от одного элемента до другого. В случае с однулением вы точно знаете, что они равны 0, и можете одному из элементов присвоить необходимое значение отступа. Если же этого не сделать, вам придется искать по приведенной мной ссылке в ответе, отступы по умолчанию для данных элементов и расчитывать необходимое оставшееся значение.

Comment: @andreyqin вы советуете что то неадекватное. 
то, что никак не решает задачу

Comment: @andreyqin зачем мне искать по приведенной ссылке чему равен дефолтный отступ? “расчитывать необходимое оставшееся значение“ что?? расчитывать оставшееся значение? расчитывать от чего? для чего расчитывать? не понимаю как ваш ответ помог автору вопроса, но имхо то, что вы советуете задачу не решило

Comment: @vox, разве я не ответил на его вопрос - откуда берется отступ? Вот смотрите - http://jsfiddle.net/7zB3m/2/ Как сделать расстояние между элементами 10px?

Comment: @andreyqin http://jsfiddle.net/XzQw7/2/ как ты и советовал, сбросить отступы и добавить отступы. чем это помогло? Вы понимаете вопрос? Как избавиться от белого пространства которое появляется от h1 но при этом не убивая отступ у h1

Answer (score 4):

Пофиксить можно заменив margin у элемента h1 на padding:

```
h1 { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 1.5rem; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить такое правило:
article h1 {
    margin-top:0;
}
Действует только внутри <article> для тега h1. Глобальный сброс не рекомендуется делать, как было указано выше. Можно, но не рекомендуется. 
С праздниками всех!

Comment: вы туда же, что и @andreyqin. Вопрос в том, как убрать белое пространство, но при этом не убивая нужный отступ у h1

Comment: @vox, а где в вопросе написано "но при этом не убивая нужный отступ у h1"? Вопрос был "Почему так и как это исправить?". Я объяснил почему так происходит? Объяснил. Отступ убрался? Убрался. А обнуление отступов у всех элементов - просто совет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите убирать дефолтные margin'ы, но при этом вас не устраивает белый фон до и после h1 присвойте родительскому блоку тега <article> одинаковый цвет (или рисунок) фона, так как через отступы между блоками просвечивается именно фон родителя (если не поняли о чем я, временно установите всем элементам страницы видимую границу ( *{border: 1px dotted black;})).
В вашем случае:

```
body { background: green; }
```